# Frattini subgroup of additive group of rational numbers

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Show that Frattini subgroup of additive group of rational numbers $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is itself, or
$$\Phi(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Q}$$

PS. My strategy is prove that group $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ hasn't maximal normal subgroup. Assume that $\mathbb{Q}$ has maximal normal subgroup $M$, then since $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ abel, so nilpotent, and satisfies the normalier condition. thus $M$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ and has index of prime.

Can you help me show that $\mathbb{Q}$ hasn't a subgroup with index of prime?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the normalizer condition holds for infinite nilpotent groups?

Comment: Yes, if $G$ is nilpotent, then it satisfies the normalizer condition

Comment: Why do you want to use nilpitency when you have an abelian group? Any subgroup is normal, so just show that the rationals do not have any proper maximal subgroup.

Comment: nilpitency imply $M$ has index of prime

Comment: @Muniain So does abelian, and it is much easier to see that this is the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

1) $\,\Bbb Q\,$ is a divisible group, meaning:

$$\forall\,q\in\Bbb Q\,\,\,and\,\,\,\forall\,0<n\in\Bbb N\,\,\,\exists\,r\in\Bbb Q\,\,\,s.t.\,\,\,q=nr$$

2) A homomorphic image of a divisible group is divisible

3) A finite group *cannot* be divisible

4) A normal subgroup $\,M\,$ of a group $\,G\,$ is a maximal proper subgroup iff $\,G/M\,$ is finite of order a prime

From all the above, it then follows that $\,\Bbb Q\,$ cannot have maximal subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a nontrivial proper subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ (it is automatically normal, since $\Bbb Q$ is commutative). We show that there is a $H\supsetneq G$ proper subgroup.

First, $G$ contains a nonzero integer $a$ (since $G$ has some nonzero elemet $a/b$, so $a\in G$ and $-a\in G$ as well). There is a smallest positive among them, we can assume that $a$ is such. If $a> 1$, then $G/a:=\{\frac xa\mid x\in G\}$ will be good: it still doesn't contain $1/a$, but already contains $1$.

Hence, we can assume that $a=1$, i.e. $\Bbb Z\subseteq G$. Then let $b:=\min\{n>0\mid \frac1n\notin G\}$. Then $G/b$ will be a good intermediate subgroup again.

Comment: How can we exclude that your definition of $b$ leads to $\infty$, i.e. show that $\{n>0|\frac1n\not\in G\}\neq\varnothing$? Does the set of unit fractions generate the rationals?

Answer (score 2):

For abelian groups, any (proper) maximal subgroup has finite index (in fact prime index), for if $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, and (as subgroups of abelian group are normal) if $G/M$ is infinite, then it contains a proper non-trivial subgroup, contradicting maximality of $M$. Therefore, it is sufficient to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ has no subgroups of finite index. For, if $M$ is subgroup of index $k\geq 1$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, consider any rational $a/b$ in reduced form. As $\mathbb{Q}/M$ has order $k$, every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ added $k$ times to $0$ will fall in $M$. But, $a/b=k(a/kb)\in M$, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}=M$. q.e.d